# How to display content by clicking on a JTree node

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtree

I have a problem with my JTree.
My JTree shows (Music,Documents,Pictures,Videos and more) like the Windows Explorer.
For example if I click on a node and this node is a folder that contains 5 (or more) images
how can I display this 5 images in 5 single JLabels???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you could approach this. The first (easier) would be to add your Images directly into the TreeModel, so that they are rendered by the DefaultTreeCellRenderer or an extension of it. The second, if you don't want to add the images to your TreeModel, would be to create a custom TreeCellRenderer which paints all of the images in one Component... But you risk running into issues over eventing / layout this way.

Also, understand that JTree uses a Renderer, and that you can't actually add any components to the JTree, you can only render data items.

Comment: thank you for your fast response this helped me a bit to handle the TreeCellRenderer but it dosnt solve my problem (but it helped alot) thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it with the following code you´ll get the path of the node where you clicked...

`MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
TreePath selPath=MyTree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY()); // <--- this was the part I searched for!`

```
        System.out.println(selPath);

         if(selPath != null) {
             if(e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                mySingleClick(selPath);

             }
             else if(e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                //myDoubleClick(selPath);
             }
         }
     }

    private void mySingleClick(TreePath selPath) {
```

`//         do whatever`

```
    }
};
        MyTree.addMouseListener(ml);
```

with this I get the path and now I can use the path to fill my JLabels with Images.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, use nested JLabel with BoxLayout in the container label:

```
JLabel mycontainer = new JLabel();
container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mycontainer, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
JLabel icon1Label = new JLabel();
JLabel icon2Label = new JLabel();
icon1Label.setIcon(icon1);
icon2Label.setIcon(icon2);
mycontainer.add(icon1Label);
mycontainer.add(icon2Label);
```

I have shown you how to store two images you can use different layouts to store more than one image.

Comment: hmmm thank you for the fast response.
I used it allready with a GridLayout and thats not the problem for example if you click on a node at your windows-Explorer on the left side, you´ll get the content on the right side. And in my case I want to display this content as images in JLabels.

Comment: Didn't got could you please elaborate or what exactly you want or may be you can put the image so we can understand. And down voters please leave a comment when you down vote it.

Comment: @Blank it means you want to change that arrow image with your thumbnail image to expand the tree node ??

Comment: No I just want to click on a JTree node (if the node is a picture) and by clicking on this node I want to view this image in a Label.